# Restrict dependency injection to in-module dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module, modular-design

**tl;dr:**

**Is there a way to restrict/lint Angular JS dependency injection to components that only exist within a module?**

I have inherited an Angular JS code base which is clearly [spaghetti code](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/spaghetti-code). 
Addtionally, most app functionality is shared between three or four modules even though the app is huge.

Since Angular doesn't restrict the namespace on a module level, the team has practically ignored module boundaries. This is in itself not a problem (Angular permits it). The problem is that the application has only rudimentary structure and components are rarely reusable, difficult to extend and I won't even think about substitution of modules.

Now, the customer has asked us to extend the app to the point where some modules should be easily substituted and I need to develop a solution.

I'm wondering about strategies and I had the idea to refactor the app by introducing module-to-module interfaces that basically implement the [facade pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade) and the [interface pattern](http://jscriptpatterns.blogspot.de/2013/01/javascript-interfaces.html).

In other words, I want services that hide module implementation from the outside world so that the module doesn't know where the data is going to and coming from. At the same time I want to use the interface pattern to ensure that the data handed to the module fulfills certain expectations.

I want to make the transition process easier and also ensure that everybody complies with the rules. Angular has no way to enforce any rules for dependency injection and the [angular plugin for eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-angular) doesn't inlcude anything along those lines. Has anyone tried this? I've googled but found nothing.

Comment: A code is worth a thousand words. What exactly 'strict/lint Angular JS dependency injection to components that only exist within a module' requirement is for? The answer most likely would be 'there's no way', so make sure that it isn't XY problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand what it is you ask me to do.

Answer (score 0):

One place to start (I don't say it's a good place) is by looking at the `_invokeQueue` from your module at runtime. you can see it via `angular.module('myModuleName')._invokeQueue`

This array contains all the stuff your module defined itself. You can try to integrate it in unit tests together with `$injector.annotate()` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#annotate) to check wether or not the required dependencies are defined in module you want.

I hope you understand this a bit?

Comment: Yep, it makes sense to me. This would be a place to start indeed but I agree that it is a hack.